# Need help moving iTunes data to updated computer when music resides on NAS

Tags: itunes, music, nas

I've had my iTunes collection on my NAS for years which is shared between several computers in my house. Computers and mobile devices can access the iTunes library. One Mac mini is used as the "manager" computer. All other devices can access the library, but all organization and management features are turned off. All management and additions to the library are done through the Mini.

I recently moved to a newer Mini and want to know the best way to make it the same as the old one.

Since the Mini is just the manager, is it as easy as adding the NAS directory through "Add to Library..."? I don't care about play counts and things like that on the new Mini, or are there some data files I should move over from the older Mini?

I'm guessing I would:

1. Change the iTunes Media folder location to point to the iTunes directory on the NAS.
2. Add NAS directory to iTunes
3. After all the songs have been added to iTunes, turn on "Keep iTunes Media folder organized" and "Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library" preferences.

Are these the right steps and right order?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the location is relationally the same, you could just pull your iTunes folder straight from the old machine ~/Music/iTunes. iTunes stores locations in an absolute form.

Comment: Would I need to pull anything? The old Mini pointed to the NAS share.

Comment: I'm pretty sure just copying that entire folder from one to the other would work. Whole lot simpler than the juggling you have to do to migrate it to a windows machine etc.